# Surface Integral over Cylinder with peculiar bounds

Tags: multivariable-calculus, surface-integrals

Been struggling with this problem for a while and can't seem to get the bounds right. The problem:
Evaluate the surface integral $$ \int\int_S \vec{F} \cdot d\vec{S} $$
$$\vec{F}(x,y,z) = x\vec{i} + y\vec{j} + 6\vec{k}$$
S is the boundary of the region enclosed by the cylinder
$$x^2 + z^2 = 1$$
and the planes
$$y = 0 , x + y = 4$$

I have done these problems before, and as soon as I saw the bounds I immediately thought polar coordinates, however, I am stuck on how to set up the bounds with the second plane. My parametrizations that I have tried for S are
$$x = cos\theta, y=y, z=sin\theta$$
which yields the cross product of the partial derivatives
$$<cos\theta, 0, sin\theta>$$
I tried plugging in bounds
$$cos\theta - 4 \leq y \leq 0$$
$$0 \leq \theta \leq 2\pi$$
with the dot product of the parametrized vector field to get the integral
$$\int_0^{2\pi}\int_{cos\theta - 4}^0cos^2\theta+6sin\theta dy d\theta$$
which yielded the wrong answer. I then tried without switching to polar coordinates so that I could have my y values as the bounds, but I couldn't even set up that integral properly. Any help is appreciated, and any tips on writing better questions are appreciated since this is my first question.

Comment: Should that be $\iint_S\vec F \cdot d\vec S$? If not, what sort of multiplication are you performing between two vectors here? And could you please be a little more clear about what constitutes the *surface* $S$. Is it the open surface consisting of just the cylindrical surface between the two planes, or is it the closed surface that is the boundary of the solid volume enclosed by the cylinder and planes? Your wording of this is quite confusing.

Comment: Sorry about that @Paul Sinclair , I have made the edits. I was doing the dot product of F and DS. Hopefully my edit clarified the surface S, as I have now put exactly what was in the problem. I am mainly confused on how to parametrize and set up the bounds for the integral, the other parts of the problem I am already familiar with. Thank you!

Comment: If that is the exact wording, then they are referring to the closed surface. That means not just the curved cylindrical face that you are parametrizing, but also the two planar faces where the planes cut that cylinder. If you only gave the value of the integral for the cylindrical face, that is likely why you got the wrong answer.